# solve with converting a string in JavaScript that is 4 letters or less to upper case and 4 letters or more to lowercase

Tags: javascript

so far I've got the array done, I just need direction in how to select said a word with 4 characters or less or more. Thanks!

```
function processString(someInput) {
            var someArray = someInput.split(" ");
            var newCSVString = "";
            for (var x = 0; x < someArray.length; x++) {
                newCSVString.push(someArray[x].charAt(3).toUpperCase() + someArray[x].toLowerCase());
```

Comment: Would be extra helpful if you could make a full example. Try creating a snippet by hitting the button with `<>` in it

Comment: and what if is exactly 4 letters? is it upper case or lower case?

Comment: What I'm looking for is a solution to if the word is less than 4 characters convert the word to upper
case and if the word is 4 characters or more, convert the word to lower case

Comment: @NickThibodeau Do you notice a slight difference between your last comment and the title of this question? Are you looking for `word.length < 4 ? word.toUpperCase() : word.toLowerCase();` for each word of a phrase separated by spaces?

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after I had posted it. I believe that is what I'm looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding of your question and comments, I think you are looking for [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
function processString(string) {
  return string.replace(/\w+/g, word => 
    word.length < 4 ? word.toUpperCase() : word.toLowerCase()
  );
}

// Example:
console.log(processString("a abc abcd abcde")); // A ABC abcd abcde
```

Comment: You might want to note this relies on arrow functions in ECMA 6 which are not supported in ANY version of IE (Edge yes) and other older browsers. A brief note on why/how you've replaced the split and array with Regex might be a good idea too.

Comment: @JonP Great suggestion. I'll probably just replace the arrow with a traditional function. Right now I am still waiting for a short confirmation by OP whether or not this is what he actually wants (regarding word splitting etc), as the question is quite confusing.

Comment: Yup, looks like the OP is splitting the string on a space and converting. The regex solution is far more elegant (to me anyway). But it hard to tell from the OPs incomplete example.